# Can't set the id to my state from URL using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-parameters

I am having a problem seting the proper ID to my state.id When the component appears for the first time, Well I tried to affect the value of the idea in the componentWillMount method but I get an error,

```
class Contrat extends Component {
    state = {
        idContrat: 4000003,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        const urlString = window.location.href;
        const url = new URL(urlString);
        const contratId = url.searchParams.get("contratId");
        if (contratId !== null && contratId.length !== 0) {
             this.props.getDetailsContrat(contratId);
        }
        this.setState({idContrat: contratId});
    }
    render(){
        return <div>{this.state.idContrat}</div>;
    }
}
```

Then I tried this :

```
class Contrat extends Component {
    state = {
        idContrat: new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("contratId");,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        const urlString = window.location.href;
        const url = new URL(urlString);
        const contratId = url.searchParams.get("contratId");
        if (contratId !== null && contratId.length !== 0) {
             this.props.getDetailsContrat(contratId);
        }
    }
    render(){
        return <div>{this.state.idContrat}</div>;
    }
}
```

But I get again an error telling that URL in not defined.

Is there a propper way to do such task ? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're using [**componentWillMount**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and upto that point you don't have
>   access to window object.

You can do it in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
        const urlString = window.location.href;
        const url = new URL(urlString);
        const contratId = url.searchParams.get("contratId");
        if (contratId !== null && contratId.length !== 0) {
             this.props.getDetailsContrat(contratId);
        }
    }
```

**On Side note:-** React added `componentWillMount` in UNSAFE List it will be deprecated in upcoming versions. Doc suggest to use `componentDidMount` instead.